# Find element via other than id, class name, etc

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have HTML like this

```
<img src="/image.png" value="-" alt="collapse">
```

I can get element like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img')
```

I see I can also get name by `id` or `class_name`.
But can I get an element by other names e.g. `src` or `value`?
I want to run a test only if `value` is `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following XPath will select all `img` elements with a `value` attribute equal to `-`:

```
//img[@value='-']
```